# javascript extjs array group multi value

Tags: javascript, arrays, extjs, underscore.js

i have a problem. i don't understand how group an array multidimensional for two o more values and then sum the field. i just tried with underscore.js but it allows only grouped by  value.
i'm use extjs 4. i have a grid and  i wnat group record for the grid

```
    var records = Etx.getCmp('grdCorpoFatturaVendita').store.getRange();
    var castellettoDataArray = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < records.length; x++) {
        console.log(records[x]);
        castellettoDataArray.push(records[x].data);
    }

var groupedData = _.groupByMulti(castellettoDataArray, 'CodiceContoContabile');
console.log(groupedData );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand you very well, but i think that you are trying to group on a grid for one field:

sencha api: [grid grouping](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.grid.feature.Grouping)

You need to add one feature on your grid view definition:

```
features: [{
    id: 'group',
    ftype: 'groupingsummary',
    groupHeaderTpl: '{name} ({rows.length})', //print the number of items in the group
    hideGroupedHeader: false
}],
```

One **example** on Sencha Api: [Example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.grid.feature.GroupingSummary)

Comment: hi thank fo you response, but its possible hie headere the group?

Comment: I  don't undestand this text: "hie headere the group". Could did you rewrite it, please?

Comment: sorry hi write with my cell ;) , hide header the group

Comment: You can replace "{name} ({rows.length})" value of "groupHeaderTpl" on blank value like this = groupHeaderTpl  : ' '... its the only want that u can do, I maybe with cls templates, but dont know. (another examples) http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/docs/Ext.grid.feature.Grouping.1/viewer.html // http://www.artsoftsolutions.ro/en/tipsatricks/extjs/28-extjs-grids-and-addremove-grouping-features